# Scale reputation by tag popularity or views

Tags: feature-request

Different subjects have different numbers of followers who view and vote on subject-related posts. If the objective is to build a wide-ranging database of questions and answers, SO needs people who will contribute to less popular topics.

A post that collects an upvote from every person who views it should lead to at least as great a reputation gain as one that is upvoted by 5%. If the second post gets at more than twenty times as many views as the first, under current rules it will lead to a greater reputation gain.

There are several ways the relationship between votes and reputation could be adjusted to reduce the subject-popularity bias. For example, reputation gain could be based on net upvotes per X views, or it could be adjusted based on the number of people who follow at least one of the question's tags.

Comment: I'm sure that there is a popularity bias in certain tags, and that people who answer questions in less-popular tags receive less reputation. But is that imbalance really a problem? Reputation isn't worth a whole lot once you've earned the basic privileges. And I don't want to lower the threshold for that any more—we already have too many people earning reputation and therefore privileges without grasping our model. Sure, you might have earned 20k or 30k if you were answering C# questions rather than (whatever questions it is you answer), but would that really be of any value to you over 10k?

Comment: @CodyGray My favorite tag is [java], which has plenty of people, so I would not benefit from this at all, even if I cared about reputation. I did not propose lowering the threshold. Any adjustment could be designed to keep the average reputation gain per upvote as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good idea. If your question gets one view and one upvote, it should not get the same amount of reputation as a question viewed by tens of thousands of people and upvoted by hundreds. The latter post was *useful* to a lot more people. The former wasn't.

I don't think it necessary to confer reputation and privileges on people who are posting content that's useful to fewer people. If you choose to be active in less popular tags, you'll have to post more (and by doing so, help more people) in order to gain as much reputation as people posting in more popular tags.

Comment: You seem to be assuming a simple linear formula. That would need to be worked out. It really depends on whether the objective is only to help the people currently asking questions, or to form as complete as possible a database of questions and answers.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Reputation doesn't do either of those things.

Comment: Unfortunately, there do seem to be people who care about reputation. The site might as well make use of that by tuning the reputation system to its objectives.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan By giving more reputation for answers that are useful to only a few people? That seems counter-productive to me. If people want more reputation, they can answer more questions. That's in line with the site's objectives.